# mongoDb get array of filter in one shot

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have mongo collection look like

```
{ day: '1', hour: 10:40 },
{ day: '1', hour: 08:40 },
{ day: '2', hour: 10:10 },
{ day: '2', hour: 08:30 },
```

I want to get this result.

```
[{day:'1', hours:['10:40','08:40']},
 {day:'2', hours:['10:10','08:30']}]
```

I try to do this with query with out success to put in hours more than one field.

```
 days= Model.aggregate
        ([{ $group: { _id: '$day', } }])
```

and then for each day

```
Model.find({day:days[0]})
```

If it's possible to do this in any prettier way.

I would like to know how :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`Aggregation Pipeline`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/aggregation-pipeline/) with [`$group`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) and [`$project`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/) stages.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$day",
      hours: {
        $push: "$hour"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      _id: 0,
      day: "$_id",
      hours: "$hours"
    }
  }
])
```

https://mongoplayground.net/p/GBmNqfQv4Wp

Comment: @GiladFuchs Awesome! Please "Accept" the answer by clicking on the checkmark. Gotta get those internet points!

Comment: of course I do.
I tried to this straight after your comment but I was need to wait 10 m.